# Microsoft test manager - recycling test cases

Tags: mstest, mtm

I have been trying lately to better make use of my previous Test scenarios in Microsoft`s Test Manager.

What I am trying to do is create a set of generic test cases which I can easily pick off and reuse on future releases/updates. As you might well know, if I try to use one of those TC in future releases/sprint PBIs what I`ll end up doing is using that TC and updating it(not copying it or clone it). So if I switch to that root TestCase it will be updated as I did on the current one(hope it makes sense so far).

So, is there any way I can recycle the TestCases as above? I have not poked around Shared Steps, but is it what I`m looking for?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Which behavior are you trying to achieve? Do you want the 'root' test case to be updated, or not?

Comment: I don`t want the root to update.

Comment: Ok, I think that's the default behavior of MTM when you copy test suites between test plans.  That's how we generally use it, just create a set of tests and copy them to a new plan when we start a new release.

Comment: The problem with that is that once you copy them, you are basically referencing them there, once you edit them, those changes will be mirrored everywhere.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I had it backwards somehow. As far as I know there's nothing built in to do what you want, so something like Shaun is saying would be how I'd do it. Automatically copying the test cases via the TFS API might be the most reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, one would be:

You could create your template list of test cases in an excel file and import them to TFS using http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/

You can also export an existing list to use with http://exporttfs2excel.codeplex.com/

Another way would be to create copies of the test cases.